# When can I use "any..." in affirmative sentences?

Tags: sentence, pronouns

According to any grammar table I can find, `any`, `anything`, `anybody` should be used in questions and negative sentences. But if I look in Google for `Anyone can do it.`, I have 6 mil. results. The sentence is obviously correct.

Why can I use `anyone` here? And are there other cases of using `any...` in affirmative sentences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Any* and its compounds are [Negative Polarity Items](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58187/15299) (questions are [Negative Triggers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/88230/15299)), though that's probably not what a grammar table would tell you. But that's not the only use of *any*.

There is also a different sense of *any*, with different grammar. It's called "Free-Choice *any*" and it belongs to that set of quantifiers like *each, every,* and *all*. Whereas *all* means 'complete group, taken together', and *every* means 'complete group, taken individually', and *each* means 'an individual, as part of a group', free-choice *any* means 'choose an individual from a group at random'; sort of a syntactic Axiom of Choice.

This *any* is normally restricted to use with modals of possibility,
i.e, it's a Possible Polarity Item like *tell time*:

- *Anybody could do that* is grammatical, but not **Anybody did that*.
- *Jimmy can already tell time* is grammatical, but not **Jimmy already told time*.

Comment: Thank you, having from you this term 'FC any', I had found many articles on the subject, such as http://allthingslinguistic.com/post/118645516892/okay-so-a-question-about-npis-is-any-always-an  BTW, it would be better, I think, to put the term at least in bold, better as a header - for better visibility in searching.

Comment: I forgot to mention that FC _any_ is the only _any_ that can appear as subject of a clause, because Negative Polarity _any_ normally follows its negative trigger, and those overwhelmingly appear in verb phrases, not subject noun phrases.

Comment: I think, your last message deserves to be included into the answer. The  main thought is important, and explanation, sorry could be more elaborated. I do not understand, what you mean to be in what phrases.