# Use of any in front of a singular noun

Tags: grammar

The boys will not receive any trophy.

Does this mean that the boys will not receive a trophy?
What does this sentence mean and is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It is grammatically correct and it does mean the boys will not receive a trophy.

Comment: It has two meanings. Either the boys will refuse all trophies presented to them. Or the boys will not be offered any trophies. It requires context to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

any means any number--one selected or whatever quantity. Merriam Webster: A : one or more —used to indicate an undetermined number or amount
*Do you have any money?*

So they won't win a trophy for coming in first, they won't win a trophy for being the tallest boys, they won't win a trophy for being the nicest boys, they won't win any trophy.

Comment: Right. _Any_ is a [Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/113582/15299), which means it can only occur grammatically in a negative context. Notice that you can't say *_The boy will receive any trophy_, because there's no negation to license the use of _any_.

Comment: @JohnLawler  As a matter of fact, you can say "the boys will receive any trophy" as in "these boys will receive any trophy to impress the girls, even if it's a trophy for finishing last".

Comment: @Centaurus: Only if _receive a trophy_ is under the control of _the boys_, rather than the judges. _To impress the girls_ is a purpose clause modifying _receive_, and requires a volitional agent subject for  _receive_, which has to be _the boys_.

Comment: @John Lawler It would be better said "The boys will _accept_ any trophy ...to impress ...", then it becomes clear that it is volitional.

Comment: @NigelJ  Yes, "accept" does the trick.

Comment: @JohnLawler   But the boys could always refuse "a trophy for finishing last" so I think there is some volition involved.

Comment: With _accept_ (which does have  a volitional agent subject and therefore works), the _any_ is the ["free choice _any_"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/440641/15299), as in _Take a card, any card_. It's not a negative polarity item, but its occurrence is also heavily restricted; often there's a modal (like _will_) involved.

Comment: @JohnLawler There's nothing wrong with saying *the boys will receive any old trophy* or *the boys will receive any available trophy* , so I don't see why there's a problem with the sentence if you remove the adjective. And, no, that doesn't need to be volitional on the part of the boys (*they will receive any trophy we can find to give them*). It may not *sound* normal, but I can think of no logical explanation for calling it ungrammatical if the version *with* an adjective is fine.