# Is it right to say “Ever have I done…?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it right to say “Ever have I done something wrong in my life“ &“Ever have I been to that basketball academy“.  So , these are two different examples I have chosen for sentence Ever have I.

haven’t done anything wrong & been to basketball academy. I want to know if my sentences are correct.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Do you want to say that you have not done anything wrong and you have not been to that basketball academy. The way you have writtem the question makes it look as though you haven't done anything wrong but you have been to the academy.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes. I’m not sure if the way I have used the sentence is correct or not.

Comment: Please could you make it clear whether the sentence you are trying to write makes a statement or asks a question.

Comment: Théoden's "Simbelmynë. Ever has it grown on the tombs of my forebears...." (Tolkien) is peerless and similar attempts to use this style should be considered with great caution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Yet' is to 'already' as what is to 'eventually'? Could 'never' do?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58181/yet-is-to-already-as-what-is-to-eventually-could-never-do)

Comment: Are you trying to use *ever* to mean *never* or to mean *always*?

Comment: The question and its accompanying explanatory comment seem partly contradictory and also incomplete. In its present form the question is therefore unclear and lacks detail.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it and the accompanying comment remain unclear and partly contradictory.

Answer (score 3):

*Ever* is not a [negative polarity item](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/npi.html) (NPI), and consequently "Ever have I..." is a **positive** statement where *ever* can [slightly awkwardly] be replaced by *always*.

It's particularly poetic: one might expect a statement such as "Ever have I loved her" meaning "I have always loved her". [A couple of examples](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Vladimir_Soloviev/h8EiTDY9FysC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22ever+have+I%22&pg=PT355&printsec=frontcover)

The counterpart is *never:* "Never have I done anything wrong." Note the use of *anything* (another NPI, to match *never*). To use *ever* as in "Ever have I..." would need to be "Ever have I done something wrong," meaning "I always get something wrong."

Comment: So , I am correct with my sentence formation right ? Not the meaning but at least sentence

Comment: "Ever have I done something wrong" is correct but extremely literary/poetic. But it doesn't mean what you want it to mean.

Comment: [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58181/yet-is-to-already-as-what-is-to-eventually-could-never-do/58187#58187) disagrees.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, it's not often I disagree with him! Feel free to write a better answer where *ever* is negative **and** valid in "Ever have I..."

Comment: From John's post: '_Ever_ is the word you're looking for. Both _ever_ and _yet_, along with _any_, are **Negative Polarity Items**.
 ... It isn't _never_, which is a negative trigger itself, not a polarity item.'

Comment: Well, as I say, feel free to demonstrate all this in an answer. "Ever have I..." is **not** negative; it means *always.*

Comment: It used to mean _always_. Now it's an NPI, and its use in *_Ever have I done ..._ makes it ungrammatical. Indeed, _ever_ is a common specimen NPI, since _any_ has another use, but _ever_ doesn't occur outside a negative environment in the 21st century. Excluding consciously archaic language, of course, if thou canst.

Comment: @JohnLawler It turns out the OED **just updated** [its entry for *ever*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/65307) this very month (December 2021). Although it’s **mostly** now used as an NPI (incl. superlative&interrogative contexts), there **are** still several common positive uses like *ever since, ever after, forever and ever*. Most other positive uses get labelled *regional, literary, rare, archaic*, or *obsolete*.  The ‘always’ sense is: “Now *regional* except (somewhat *literary*) with *be* and complement expressing habitual or typical characteristics: e.g. *he was ever one to take risks*.”

Comment: @tchrist: Yup. Fixed phrases and archaic expressions. That's the place where old words go to die after they've evolved new roles.

Comment: I think you'll find I mentioned the word "poetic" a couple of times. It's also entirely possible that English English differs from American English.

Answer (score 2):

It is just about possible grammatically to say "Ever have I..." but it would not be normal English and would mean that you were in the habit of doing the thing, for instance "Ever have I brushed my teeth twice a day" would mean that your dental hygiene was good.

I think what you mean to say is "*Never* have I done anything wrong." which does mean what you want to say, is a bit more common but is still not really normal conversational English.

The most normal things to say would be "I have never done anything wrong" and "I have never been to that baseball academy."

Answer (score -3):

It's certainly not standard usage or grammar. I think I can see it just about working as direct speech when the emphasis is on the word ever.

Have you considered trying:

> Have I ever done something wrong in my life?